# Anyways of making a Lucene field stored as well as streamed through a reader

Tags: lucene, stream, field, store

Is there a way of creating a field in Lucene which can accept a reader or InputStream and also store the content of it? I want to store the data so that it can be used at the time of Highlighting and I want to stream the data because the content of the documents might be really large.

I do not see a constructor for a field that allows me to use a reader as well as lets me store the value.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your documents are not too large, just read them into memory first, and then specify the resulting value as a String when adding a new Field. If the documents are large, split them into manageable chunks and perform the above operation on each chunk. Make sure to use the same field name for each chunk, so that Lucene will search over all values.

Example:

```
IndexWriter writer = ...
String id = ...
String[] lines = ...
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("id", id, Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED, TermVector.NO );
for (String line: lines) {
    doc.add(new Field("text", line, Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED, TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS);
}
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

Lucene will automatically merge the values specified at each add with the same field name, so that it can search over the pooled set.

Comment: But wouldn't I get into issue when I want to show a cached copy or want to do highlighting? When you say keep the same field name what do you mean by it? Create multiple fields with the same "name" and add it to documents?

Comment: Hello thanks for your useful information. What I still don't understand: why it is working like this. Because when I try to add some large elements as strings directly it fails because of the memory limits, but this way it works despite I hold all the data in memory. I inspected the Lucene source code and I didn't find any kind of swap. What am I missing?