# Parse stream (reader) with Tika and index it with Lucene simultaneously

Tags: lucene, streaming, apache-tika

I am reading docs and wonder if there is a possibility not to read the stream twice in order to parse it with Tika, get the metadata + the contents and index it in Lucene?

I'd like to avoid storing the file in memory after parsing as it could be too large.

I am reading the following link and it seems that it holds the parsed document contents in memory - http://johnreece.com/wordpress/2011/03/13/a-concise-tikalucene-content-parsing-and-indexing-example/

(Maybe somehow connected with "[Anyways of making a Lucene field stored as well as streamed through a reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213691/anyways-of-making-a-lucene-field-stored-as-well-as-streamed-through-a-reader)")

(Additionally, I'd like to be sure that Lucene's `TextField` deals with `Reader` without making `String` from it, which should consume the memory)

Comment: Why would you be reading the stream twice? Surely it gets read once by Tika, then you set the metadata and contents into Lucene in one go?

Comment: Then it means that contents would be stored in memory, which is another thing i'd wish to avoid. The file could be very huge thus causing out of memory error, couldn't it?

Comment: Lucene normally has a limit on the amount of data it'll store in a field for a document (max terms), when your file is converted to plain text by Tika that won't take that much memory